# set colored-stats ignores $LS_COLORS

Tags: bash, autocomplete, ls, macports, inputrc

### Problem

I am trying to make auto-completed files be colored according to `$LS_COLORS` in bash. But autocompletion ignores my `$LS_COLORS` variable and gets color values from some-place else.

### Setting

I have a `dircolors` file and the following declarations in `.bashrc`:

```
eval `dircolors $HOME/.config/bash/dircolors`

bind 'set colored-stats on'
bind 'set colored-completion-prefix on'

alias ls='ls --group-directories-first --color=auto'
```

The `ls` output is colored as expected (screenshot):

[image: i1]

But the autocompletion is way off:

[image: i2]

However, if I remove my custom `$LS_COLORS` then the output becomes the same as autocompletion:

[image: i3]

### More details

`bash`, `ls`, and `dircolors` installed via `macports` (ports: "bash" and "coreutils")

OS: macOS 13.2.1
bash: GNU bash, version 5.2.15
ls: (GNU coreutils) 9.1

`$TERM:` xterm-256color
`$LS_COLORS`:

```
no=00;38;5;0:fi=00;38;5;0:di=01:ex=00;38;5;1:ln=07;38;5;2:or=07;38;5;1:pi=07;38;5;12:so=07;38;5;10:do=07;38;5;10:bd=07;38;5;3:cd=07;38;5;3:ow=04;01:tw=04;01:*.tar=00;38;5;5:*.tgz=00;38;5;5:*.arj=00;38;5;5:*.taz=00;38;5;5:*.lzh=00;38;5;5:*.lzma=00;38;5;5:*.tlz=00;38;5;5:*.txz=00;38;5;5:*.zip=00;38;5;5:*.z=00;38;5;5:*.Z=00;38;5;5:*.dz=00;38;5;5:*.gz=00;38;5;5:*.lz=00;38;5;5:*.xz=00;38;5;5:*.bz2=00;38;5;5:*.bz=00;38;5;5:*.tbz=00;38;5;5:*.tbz2=00;38;5;5:*.tz=00;38;5;5:*.deb=00;38;5;5:*.rpm=00;38;5;5:*.jar=00;38;5;5:*.rar=00;38;5;5:*.ace=00;38;5;5:*.zoo=00;38;5;5:*.cpio=00;38;5;5:*.7z=00;38;5;5:*.rz=00;38;5;5:*.apk=00;38;5;5:*.gem=00;38;5;5:*.zst=00;38;5;5:*.gpg=04;38;5;0:*.jpg=00;38;5;3:*.JPG=00;38;5;3:*.jpeg=00;38;5;3:*.gif=00;38;5;3:*.bmp=00;38;5;3:*.pbm=00;38;5;3:*.pgm=00;38;5;3:*.ppm=00;38;5;3:*.tga=00;38;5;3:*.xbm=00;38;5;3:*.xpm=00;38;5;3:*.tif=00;38;5;3:*.tiff=00;38;5;3:*.png=00;38;5;3:*.PNG=00;38;5;3:*.svg=00;38;5;3:*.svgz=00;38;5;3:*.mng=00;38;5;3:*.pcx=00;38;5;3:*.dl=00;38;5;3:*.xcf=00;38;5;3:*.xwd=00;38;5;3:*.yuv=00;38;5;3:*.cgm=00;38;5;3:*.emf=00;38;5;3:*.eps=00;38;5;3:*.CR2=00;38;5;3:*.ico=00;38;5;3:*.mov=00;38;5;3:*.MOV=00;38;5;3:*.mpg=00;38;5;3:*.mpeg=00;38;5;3:*.m2v=00;38;5;3:*.mkv=00;38;5;3:*.ogm=00;38;5;3:*.mp4=00;38;5;3:*.m4v=00;38;5;3:*.mp4v=00;38;5;3:*.vob=00;38;5;3:*.qt=00;38;5;3:*.nuv=00;38;5;3:*.wmv=00;38;5;3:*.asf=00;38;5;3:*.rm=00;38;5;3:*.rmvb=00;38;5;3:*.flc=00;38;5;3:*.avi=00;38;5;3:*.fli=00;38;5;3:*.flv=00;38;5;3:*.gl=00;38;5;3:*.m2ts=00;38;5;3:*.divx=00;38;5;3:*.webm=00;38;5;3:*.aac=00;38;5;3:*.au=00;38;5;3:*.flac=00;38;5;3:*.mid=00;38;5;3:*.midi=00;38;5;3:*.mka=00;38;5;3:*.mp3=00;38;5;3:*.mpc=00;38;5;3:*.ogg=00;38;5;3:*.ra=00;38;5;3:*.wav=00;38;5;3:*.m4a=00;38;5;3:*.pdf=00;38;5;4:*.PDF=00;38;5;4:*.html=00;38;5;4:*.HTML=00;38;5;4:*.doc=00;38;5;4:*.docx=00;38;5;4:*.rtf=00;38;5;4:*.ppt=00;38;5;4:*.pptx=00;38;5;4:*.odt=00;38;5;4:*.odp=00;38;5;4:*.epub=00;38;5;4:*.pl=00;38;5;0:*.PL=00;38;5;0:*.py=00;38;5;0:*.pm=00;38;5;0:*.tt=00;38;5;0:*.yml=00;38;5;0:*.sql=00;38;5;0:*.css=00;38;5;0:*.js=00;38;5;0:*.sh=00;38;5;0:*.R=00;38;5;0:*.r=00;38;5;0:*.hs=00;38;5;0:*.rb=00;38;5;0:*.cc=00;38;5;0:*.c=00;38;5;0:*.lua=00;38;5;0:*.vim=00;38;5;0:*.m=00;38;5;0:*.1=00;38;5;0:*.h=00;38;5;0:*.hh=00;38;5;0:*.tex=00;38;5;0:*.bib=00;38;5;0:*.Rd=00;38;5;0:*.rmd=00;38;5;0:*.Rmd=00;38;5;0:*Makefile=00;38;5;0:*Snakefile=00;38;5;0:*do=00;38;5;0:*Doxyfile=00;38;5;0:*config=00;38;5;0:*.conf=00;38;5;0:*.cfg=00;38;5;0:*.yml=00;38;5;0:*README=00;38;5;0:*README.txt=00;38;5;0:*README.md=00;38;5;0:*README.markdown=00;38;5;0:*TODO=00;38;5;0:*todo=00;38;5;0:*NOTE=00;38;5;0:*note=00;38;5;0:*.xlm=00;38;5;6:*.xls=00;38;5;6:*.xlsx=00;38;5;6:*.csv=00;38;5;6:*.tsv=00;38;5;6:*.Rds=00;38;5;6:*.rds=00;38;5;6:*.RDS=00;38;5;6:*.Rda=00;38;5;6:*.rda=00;38;5;6:*.RDA=00;38;5;6:*.Rdata=00;38;5;6:*.RData=00;38;5;6:*.RDATA=00;38;5;6:*.sav=00;38;5;6:*.mat=00;38;5;6:*.json=00;38;5;6:*.bed=00;38;5;6:*.idat=00;38;5;6:*.ods=00;38;5;6:*.log=00;38;5;15:*.bak=00;38;5;15:*.aux=00;38;5;15:*.lof=00;38;5;15:*.lol=00;38;5;15:*.lot=00;38;5;15:*.out=00;38;5;15:*.toc=00;38;5;15:*.bbl=00;38;5;15:*.blg=00;38;5;15:*~=00;38;5;15:*#=00;38;5;15:*.part=00;38;5;15:*.incomplete=00;38;5;15:*.swp=00;38;5;15:*.tmp=00;38;5;15:*.temp=00;38;5;15:*.o=00;38;5;15:*.pyc=00;38;5;15:*.class=00;38;5;15:*.cache=00;38;5;15:*.url=04;38;5;2:
```

### Things I tried

1. Using very simple `$LS_COLORS` definition - no effect
2. Setting both `$LSCOLORS` and `$LS_COLORS` - no effect
3. Removing `ls` alias and setting `dircolors` before `colored-stats on` - no effect
4. Returning to native ls in macOS and using `$LSCOLORS` - output color changed but completion color remained

Comment: Was `bind 'set colored-stats on'` done after `LS_COLORS` was defined? Try also [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console).

Comment: I tried both: sourcing before and after. And now tried to manually source whole .bashrc on top, but didn't have an effect. Currently trying to delete everything else from .bashrc and only leave the $LS_COLORS lines.

Comment: @harrymc sadly that didn't help either... lost at what else I can potentially try